# Session time PHP

Tags: php, session

HeIIo, I have two independent Sessions going on, and I want one of them to be stored for one hour only and another one for a month.
What I found so far is that if I use

```
session_set_cookie_params(3600 * 24 * 30);
session_start();
```

it will store a session for a month, and if I use

```
session_set_cookie_params(3600);
session_start();
```

the session will last for an hour. My first question is will it work if the user closed his browser?

I'm trying to do

```
$_SESSION['userId'] = $userId; 
//need this one to last for a week (prolong if user stays active)
```

and

```
$_SESSION['someOtherTimer'] = $someOtherTimer; 
// need this one to last for an hour (prolong if user stays active)
```

Those two SESSION variables are called independently from different functions. My second question is how can I set different expiration time for those two session variables?

Thank you

Comment: Sessions by definition are only supposed to persist until the browser is closed. Cookies themselves are what you'd use for a persistent data store over browser sessions. I think you might be getting these a little confused.

Comment: ok, thats what I thought but wasn't sure. Can you give an example how to store session with cookies for a month (with prolonging if user stays active)?

Comment: **Set:** `setcookie('cookiename', 'cookie value', time()+30*24*60*60)`, **get:** `$_COOKIE['cookiename']`. To "prolong", simply keep setting the cookie with that expiration date and the same value. **Disclaimer:** don't store sensitive data in cookies.